# Black dots on the image in DataGridView ImageColumn and CrystalReports Blob Field

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, image-resizing

When I try to resize the image before adding to DataGridView ImageColumn or Crystal Reports (Blob), I get black dots on the image:

[https://ibb.co/j6ZWDC7]([image with dots](https://ibb.co/j6ZWDC7))

[https://ibb.co/Wc9c51Z]([original image](https://ibb.co/Wc9c51Z))

[https://ibb.co/pWFTm5w]([Exif data](https://ibb.co/pWFTm5w))

Edit: In Crystal Reports the size of BlobField is 4,87cm(w) x 4,66cm(h), "Can Grow" disabled. I calculated the given size from the Blob field and I got 184px(w) x 176px(h), so this values I used for resize.

(I have another function that shows the original image in a PictureBox and that works without a problem - shows without the black dots)

I have the following code (this code I use for Crystal Reports - IBlobFieldObject using dataset):

```
        utils.Settings.LoadImage(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i], "imageUrl", foldername + utils.Settings.Logo, 184, 176);
...
        public static void LoadImage(DataRow objDataRow, string strImageField, string FilePath, int width, int height)
        {
            try
            {
                Image image = null;

                if (Path.GetFileName(FilePath).ToLower().Contains("thumb"))
                {
                    objDataRow[strImageField] = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    image = utils.Settings.resizeImage(Image.FromFile(FilePath), new Size(width, height));

                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, GetImageFormat(FilePath));
                    objDataRow[strImageField] = m.ToArray();
                }                         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
...
        public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
            int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

            float nPercent = 0;
            float nPercentW = 0;
            float nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
                nPercent = nPercentH;
            else
                nPercent = nPercentW;

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

            return (Image)imgToResize.GetThumbnailImage(destWidth, destHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

Expecting a clear image, without black dots.

Comment: Don't use `GetThumbnailImage()` then. Draw the image into a new Bitmap, specifying the new size and set `InterpolationMode` to `HighQualityBicubic`